# Parse command line arguments into a IP : Port format using argparse in Python

Tags: python, sockets, argparse

I'm trying to use argparse to parse 2 command line arguments to my script in the following format `client.py [-n IP] [-p PORT]`

So far I've implemented the following:

```
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
## Gets IP and PORT from command line and parses them
ConnectionInfo = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ConnectionInfo.add_argument("-n",  default=socket.gethostname())
ConnectionInfo.add_argument("-p", type=int, default='58000')
ConnectionInfoParsed = ConnectionInfo.parse_args()
# Saves the parsed IP and Port
HOST = ConnectionInfoParsed.n
PORT = ConnectionInfoParsed.p
# Connects to Server
connection.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

However when I execute:

```
py client.py [-n 127.0.0.1] [-p 58000]
```

I get the following error

```
usage: client.py [-h] [-n N] [-p P]
client.py: error: unrecognized arguments: [-n 127.0.0.1] [-p 58000]
```

Can anyone help me out where is the problem here, also where does the `[-h]` argument in the error comes from since I don't add any argument for it?

Comment: I'd expect you to use `py client.py -n 127.0.0.1 -p 58000`.  No brackets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As hpaulj mentioned

> I'd expect you to use py client.py -n 127.0.0.1 -p 58000. No brackets.

The issue is solved